# Unity, can I publish to Google Play an app with only 32-bit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I have an Android app which was developed on Unity. Can I pusblish it to Google Play without IL2CPP? (It works incorrectly when it is built with IL2CPP, but correctly - with Mono).

Comment: As far as I know you must support 64-bit. Seems like you have some debugging to do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about an app store policy, not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation. You must support 64 bit.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/64-bit

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. The question is off-topic, but... this should be a comment, not an answer.